# No Routing error when trying to add custom action to a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I am trying to add an custom action to a resource but I get a routing error `No route matches [GET] "/products/list/up"`. I have tried commenting out the URI in routes.rb, but they also don't work. What am I doing wrong?

I have this in the `routes.rb`:

```
 namespace :api, :defaults =>{format: 'json'} do
 scope module:  :v1 ,constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version:1, default: true) do

resources :products do
member do
  match  "/list/up" =>"products#product_list" ,:via=>:get
  #get "/list/up" , :action=>"product_list"
  #get "/list/up" , :to=>"product_list"
end
end
 end
 end
```

in the `products_controller.rb`:

```
def product_list
  @products= Product.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @products.to_json}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `collection` instead of `member` as you don't provide any `id` in the path:

```
resources :products do
    collection do # <-----<
        get  "/list/up" =>"products#product_list"
    end
end
```

Running `rake routes` gives:

```
list_up_products GET    /products/list/up(.:format)  products#product_list
        products GET    /products(.:format)          products#index
                 POST   /products(.:format)          products#create
     new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)      products#new
    edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
         product GET    /products/:id(.:format)      products#show
                 PUT    /products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                 DELETE /products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
```

Comment: That didnt work either. Rake routes shows this `products/list/up(.:format)  products#product_list`

Comment: @katie Isn't that what you wanted? To use `/products/list/up` URL to trigger your `products#product_list` action?

Comment: yes but still gives me `No route matches [GET] "/products/list/up"`

Comment: @katie I tried the snippet I posted on my dummy application. It worked! Maybe you just need to restart your app, or you didn't remove some old code out of your routes.rb?

Comment: I didnt mention before for simplicity, i am using scope in routes and now i get uninitialized constant `Api::V1::Api` while my controller is under Api::V1

Comment: @katie Please, provide the URL you want to have. If it's `products/list/up`, then you have to set `path: ''` in your `namespace :api` line to avoid `api` form appearing in your URL.